# Window Application submission failed to extract imported API information

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps, nwjs

I am trying to publish an application to the windows store and it keeps failing. The error I receive is the following.

[(App manifest) Failed to extract imported API information for this application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c34vR.png)

[(Supported APIs) Failed to extract imported API information for this application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XapYl.png)

Could someone tell me what am I missing. I am not able to identify the API and the reason behind this error.

This application is build with [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/)

Comment: Have you make some research about your error?

Comment: Yes i did some research to find out the error by checking logs created by MSIX packaging tool. Also, i have checked so many blogs to find out the solution but didn't get any idea about the API.

Comment: For the first screenshot, it looks you missed some capability. and for the second screenshot, you have used unsupported api, please try to run your app in release  model and test again.

Comment: This question is not about "winapi" or Windows API (formerly Win32 API), the "API" term in your question relates to "Microsoft Store submission API" which is a different thing from "winapi", so I have edited your questions and removed the "winapi" tag. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT, Thanks for the help but I am not able to run my application in release mode. It would be great if you provide me steps to do the same.

Comment: Click Solution Configuration selectbox select Release then right click your project -> build-> check Compile with nettive tool chain

Comment: Does the application run if you side-load to a different computer, or does it have dependencies outside of the package? Can you run the **Windows App Cert Kit** locally? Unfortunately there isn't enough info to help here.